# Excel workbook with data linked to another workbook is fetching data even though the sourced workbook is renamed/replaced or deleted

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have created a workbook say A which has product specification along with their product code in normal range format. The second workbook say B is having a table with calculated columns containing index match formulas to fetch data from the workbook A. As soon as I fill Product no. in product code column in WB B the calculated columns automatically fills data in the row by Index-Matching it from WB A's data. The setup overall is working fine.
The issue is that while I wanted to get a VBA customized notification to user if the two workbook's link is broken. So what I did is I deleted the WB A temporarily. But now when I open WB B although it is showing the "We can't update some links...." dialogue box. But when I enter Product No. in the cell it still able to fetch data somehow. I'm puzzled how WB B is still able to get the data. I Tried multiple times with different values but it is still able to fetch the data somehow.

Instead of deleting the WB A I tried renaming or replacing but WB B it still behaves the same. It seems like the WB B has fetched all the data from A and stored somewhere.
The downside is that I will not be able to be sure that the fetched data is latest or not.

Comment: Er, check the formula and see where is it pointing?

Comment: Although since then we decided to not use excel for this same issue. But just for update the formula is same and still point to that workbook only. Strange issue, wish I could post the workbook but can't due to workplace IT policies.